# In Windows 7, how to show day name in system tray clock?

Tags: windows-7, time, date

Without installing third-party software, how do I display the day in the clock in the lower-right system tray clock in Windows 7.  For example:  "Tuesday"  (in addition to normal time and date display)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to change the date format.

- Open Control Panel->Clock, Language, Region->Change the date, time, or number format->Additional Settings...->Date tab
- Prepend **dddd** to the Short date: format

[image]

You'll then see the day name in the tray clock.

[image]

Of course, this will change the short date format throughout the OS, which may or may not be a problem for you.

Comment: Grt. Can also use `ddd M/d/yyyy` for the date to display like `Mon 12/16/2013`.

Comment: That's the problem: it affects date/time format in all apps, including Excel, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

Simply make the Taskbar a little bigger and it will display the date.

[image]

In addition, I am not sure, but will look up and see if there is a registry hack or alternative way to do it without stretching the bar.

Comment: Yep, that's the only way I've found thus far.